# Google Analytics Reg Ex isn't tracking goal URL

Tags: regex, google-analytics, tracking

Alright, i've played around with this for over a week now and I can't get it to work. Using a regular expression match:

**My GOAL URL:**
category=thanks
This is not tracking correctly

**My only goal step:**
/s.nl\?c=1025622&n=5&sc=[0-9]+&ext=T&add=[0-9]&whence=
This is tracking correctly but it is saying everybody exits on this step and does not go to my goal URL

Upon looking at pages that contain category=thanks, I found the following tracked URLs

/s.nl?c=1025622&sc=44&category=thanks&whence=&n=5
/s.nl?c=1025622&sc=44&category=thanks&n=5
/s.nl?c=1025622&sc=44&category=thanks&whence=&n=5&redirect_count=1&did_javascript_redirect=T
/s.nl?c=1025622&n=5&sc=44&category=thanks&it=A&login=T

along with a bunch of other containing category=thanks. As I obviously can't compensate for all these changing URL, I figured just having "category=thanks" would work, but apparently not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `category=thanks` statement is not a regular expression that matches the URLs you mentioned. It would apply for filters and segments where there's a 'URI contains' option, but not a full match.

I beleive you have 2 options:

1. Go to Content report in GA, choose a larger time period (like a year) and add a `category=thanks` filter. You'll get all possible goal URLs. For them you'll have to write a regular expression. From what you describe, your URL structure is a mess (too many parametrs), so take a look at option 2.
2. Add a small script to your goal page that would redirect your visitors to a page with a clean url. Something like a conditional statement saying `if (URL contains category=thanks) {redirect to /thankyou.html}`, then use this thankyou.html as a goal in GA.